# How soon can I travel back on ESTA after a 2 and a half month stay?

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, proof-of-funds

Ok so I went to USA end of september and came back a few days ago. I had originally booked 3 weeks but extended my trip whilst I was there. I am  planning to return in February, exactly 2 months after coming back to the UK. I want to stay for just under the 90 days. I have no real ties to the UK that can be proved unless anyone can help me with things I could use. Family here apparently does not count. What are my chances of being sent back? I know its hard to answer that but I am getting more and more worried now.

Will this be ok? I know it says you can have as many visits as you like under the visa waiver program but it also says a reasonable length of time between visits. would two months be reasonable? I do not work I claim benefits in the UK so I would not be able to stay much longer than I plan to in the US. I can prove I have enough money to stay in the US without working. I would be staying with a friend. Would I be better off booking a shorter return trip of a couple of weeks and then paying to change my departure or because I did this before would that be a red flag? I just want some reassurance or advice really. Anybody else have experience with this?

Comment: Some advice: Do not try to deceive the immigration officers. If they catch you in even a little white lie (and they're very good at it) you will be found inadmissible. For instance, you should not say you are visiting a friend if your "friend" will say you are in a relationship, or vice versa. Second, on your next journey, use an automated passport control kiosk if the airport you arrive at has them.

Comment: They do have the automated kiosks but was unsure if that would be more of a risk of getting pulled into secondary or if i should just speak to an officer so it doesnt look like im trying to sneak through? I posted on another forum and everyone keeps saying I am breaking the rules and will be turned back?? Would you think 2 months away is a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: You're eligible to use the kiosks, so use them! Why are you worried? What have you _not_ said here that is relevant?

Comment: I wasnt overly worried before was just looking into it but then I started to see a few posts that said they may not like the fact of two visits in a short space of time. My concern is the length of time I would stay away. 2months away after 2 months in and also the fact that I dont have any real ties to england. The posts on the other forum have really scared me! Im also worried incase the fact that I extended my stay last time will raise questions. As for the "friend" side of it thats complicated! we would decide closer to the time what our friendship is.

Comment: @concernedesta first, it's okay to have a complicated or ambiguous relationship that is still not exactly defined.  Just be honest.  The main reason people worry about time between visits is that the Schengen area has strict rules with precise limits on the number of days one can stay.  The US doesn't have such well-defined limits, which can, I suppose, be good or bad depending on who interviews you at the border.

Comment: Well I just rang the US embassay ESTA department and the man said that as he would not be the officer at the POE he could not give a difinitive answer but the fact that I would be looking to spend 5 and a half months in a short period of time that they would want to take a closer look at me and it would be up to me to prove i was going back home. Thats not so easy for me as I dont have real ties. no job no rent agreement etc. What other things could I use as proof that im going to return? Would it be better to book a shorter trip? show I have tourist type plans for whilst I am there? HELP!!